# TypeError: _this.store.getState is not a function when using connect from Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I first run the server with `node app.js` everything is fine I get `listening on 5050`.Then I go to localhost:5050/ and I get these warnings in the console where the server is running.

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `store.subscribe` was not specified in `Provider`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required child context `store.subscribe` was not specified in `Provider`.
```

The component renders fine there but once I go onto localhost:5050/ballerviews I get this on server

```
TypeError: _this.store.getState is not a function
    at new Connect (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connect.js:133:38)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:148:18)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:241:44)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:591:32)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:479:29)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/freddiecabrera/Desktop/ullibol-client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
```

You can view the full project on my [Github](https://github.com/freddiecabrera/ullibol-client) since I feel by viewing it there you can get the best understanding.

I have been trying to figure this out all day today and I could not. It was working fine before I tried to render on the server. I appreciate the help and if you need any more info to answer the question please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are just two small issues:

## 1. ES2015 module -> CommonJS

You are using an ES2015 `export default` in `src/store.js`, however you then require it via CommonJS in `app.js` on [line #11](https://github.com/freddiecabrera/ullibol-client/blob/6c43c4cc63a1eaa92126d096a5473e982e0c5c28/src/store.js).

This is fine of course, but you'll want to access the default property when requiring. Update the line as follows:

```js
// Old
const store = require('./src/store.js')

// New
const store = require('./src/store.js').default
```

## 2. Calling `document` on the server

On [line #41](https://github.com/freddiecabrera/ullibol-client/blob/6c43c4cc63a1eaa92126d096a5473e982e0c5c28/src/components/BallerViews.jsx#L41) of `src/components/BallerViews.jsx` you are accessing the document, which won't exist on the server. A quick fix would be to wrap that line in a conditional:

```js
// Old
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#0e0e13'

// New
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#0e0e13'
}
```

Comment: Damn! Thank you so much, you saved me I really appreciate your help. So basically anytime I want to access the document or the window I have to wrap it in a conditional?

Comment: @FreddieCabrera Yes, but only when you're server-rendering. Node doesn't have knowledge of the DOM. A popular practice is to globals like `__CLIENT__` and `__SERVER__` so that you can target each easily. You could do this in your server entrypoint (app.js) and in your webpack config. I've created a gist to show you how to set it up: https://gist.github.com/iamlacroix/38fb4ce4670313bae2a913bbc54b2ae3

Comment: @MichaelLaCroix .default fixed this for me as well.  It's pretty hard to follow the best practices as so many examples mix ES2015 vs legacy.